# Optimize the spark dataframe upsert approach

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, upsert

I have tried below the best approach I could think of to upsert the new data (in sourceDF) on the existing data (in targetDF) making use of the specified primary keys.

```
val primaryKeyList = List("header1")
val primaryKeyRowsToDropFromTarget = 
targetDF.select(primaryKeyList.head, primaryKeyList.tail:_*)
.intersect(sourceDF.select(primaryKeyList.head, primaryKeyList.tail:_*))
.withColumn("dropColumnFlag",lit("yes"))

val upsertedDF = 
targetDF.join(primaryKeyRowsToDropFromTarget , primaryKeyList.toSeq , "left_outer")
.filter("dropColumnFlag is null").drop("dropColumnFlag")
.union(sourceDF)
```

The above approach follows the sequence of steps:

1. Identify primary key column or combination of columns to get the composite key.
2. Identify which rows to be dropped from the targetDF whose primary key column(s) match the sourceDF. And append a flag as "yes" to those rows.
3. Use left outer join on the targetDF to mark those rows with the flag which would be updated.
4. Filter out the unmarked targetDF rows which would not be updated and drop the flag column.
5. Finally, consolidate this filtered out targetDF data with the sourceDF data.

The following example, will show the sourceDF, targetDF and expected upsertedDF:

```
targetDF: 

header1,header2,header3
1,A,10
2,B,14
3,C,17
4,D,32
5,E,232

sourceDF

header1,header2,header3
6,F,102
7,G,141
8,H,175
9,J,103
10,L,141
3,X,112
1,Z,90

upsertedDF

header1,header2,header3
2,B,14
4,D,32
5,E,232
6,F,102
7,G,141
8,H,175
9,J,103
10,L,141
3,X,112
1,Z,90
```

Is there an optimized approach or logic to achieve the same result? I will be dealing with data in the magnitude of more than 10-15 GBs to apply this logic on. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `except` , `left_anti` and `unionAll` functions.

**Example:**

```
sourceDF.show()
//+-------+-------+-------+
//|header1|header2|header3|
//+-------+-------+-------+
//|      6|      F|    102|
//|      7|      G|    141|
//|      8|      H|    175|
//|      9|      J|    103|
//|     10|      L|    141|
//|      3|      X|    112|
//|      1|      Z|     90|
//+-------+-------+-------+

targetDF.show()
//+-------+-------+-------+
//|header1|header2|header3|
//+-------+-------+-------+
//|      1|      A|     10|
//|      2|      B|     14|
//|      3|      C|     17|
//|      4|      D|     32|
//|      5|      E|    232|
//+-------+-------+-------+

sourceDF.except(targetDF).unionAll(targetDF.join(sourceDF,Seq("header1"),"left_anti")).show()

//+-------+-------+-------+
//|header1|header2|header3|
//+-------+-------+-------+
//|      6|      F|    102|
//|      9|      J|    103|
//|      1|      Z|     90|
//|      3|      X|    112|
//|     10|      L|    141|
//|      7|      G|    141|
//|      8|      H|    175|
//|      2|      B|     14|
//|      4|      D|     32|
//|      5|      E|    232|
//+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: @Highdef, If the answer helped you to resolve issue.. Could you **`upvote and accept`** the answer to close this thread! :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work